# Trouble Incrementing a counter by more than one

Tags: ios, swift

So I'm working on an app and I'm trying to get a UILabel to increase by a certain amount every time a button is pressed. This is what I have:

Object:

```
class NewsArticle: NSObject{
    static var counter: Int = 10
}
```

Label:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tokenCounter: UILabel!
```

Button:

```
    @IBAction func tenTokens(sender: AnyObject) {
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Do you want to purchase 10 Tokens?", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes!", style:UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:{(alert: UIAlertAction!) in self.tokenCounter.text = (++NewsArticle.counter).description}))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    //self.tokenCounter.text = (NewsArticle.counter).description

}
```

This function right now only increases the counter by 1. Everytime I try and change '(++NewsArticle.counter).description' to '(NewsArticle.counter+10).description' it only temporarily changes the value of the IBOutlet. If I click a different button (similarly named oneToken) that only does ++, then it'll change the label back.

Example sequence:

Label = 10

click button 'Ten Tokens.'

Label = 20

click button 'One Token'

Label = 11

click button 'Ten Tokens'

Label = 21

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    @IBAction func tenTokens(sender: AnyObject) {
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Do you want to purchase 10 Tokens?", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes!", style:UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:{(alert: UIAlertAction!) in 
            NewsArticle.counter = NewsArticle.counter + 10
            self.tokenCounter.text = (NewsArticle.counter).description
}))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        //self.tokenCounter.text = (NewsArticle.counter).description

    }
```

You should change the value by `NewsArticle.counter = NewsArticle.counter + 10`

I am just adding to the answer:

The ++ operator will increment the NewArticle variable with one and return that value. The + operator will not increment NewArticle value but just return added value so NewArticle variable will be unchanged and hence your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just a tiny improvement to WenchenHuangs answer.

Instead of writing

```
NewsArticle = NewsArticle + 10
```

You could write

```
NewsArticle += 10
```

And get the same result.

Probably just a matter of style/taste I guess